# Is there a way to get a Scala HashMap to automatically initialize values?'

Tags: scala

I thought it could be done as follows

```
val hash = new HashMap[String, ListBuffer[Int]].withDefaultValue(ListBuffer())
hash("A").append(1)
hash("B").append(2)
println(hash("B").head)
```

However the above prints the unintuitive value of 1. I would like

```
hash("B").append(2)
```

To do something like the following behind the scenes

```
if (!hash.contains("B")) hash.put("B", ListBuffer())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`withDefaultValue` uses *exactly the same value* each time.  In your case, it's the same empty `ListBuffer` that gets shared by everyone.

If you use `withDefault` instead, you could generate a new `ListBuffer` every time, but it wouldn't get stored.

So what you'd really like is a method that would know to add the default value.  You can create such a method inside a wrapper class and then write an implicit conversion:

```
class InstantiateDefaults[A,B](h: collection.mutable.Map[A,B]) {
  def retrieve(a: A) = h.getOrElseUpdate(a, h(a))
}
implicit def hash_can_instantiate[A,B](h: collection.mutable.Map[A,B]) = {
  new InstantiateDefaults(h)
}
```

Now your code works as desired (except for the extra method name, which you could pick to be shorter if you wanted):

```
val hash = new collection.mutable.HashMap[
  String, collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]
].withDefault(_ => collection.mutable.ListBuffer())

scala> hash.retrieve("A").append(1)

scala> hash.retrieve("B").append(2)

scala> hash("B").head
res28: Int = 2
```

Note that the solution (with the implicit) doesn't need to know the default value itself at all, so you can do this once and then default-with-addition to your heart's content.

Comment: Is there some way to overwrite the default behaviour of hash("B").append(2)?

Comment: You can extend `apply`, but that gets ugly quickly.  You're better off using a separate method IMO.

Comment: @deltanova You can pimp `HashMap[A,ListBuffer[B]]` to have a method `def append[A,B](key: A, value: B) = getOrElseUpdate(key)(new LB...).append(value)`.

Answer (score 10):

Use `getOrElseUpdate` to provide the default value at the point of access:

```
scala> import collection.mutable._
import collection.mutable._

scala> def defaultValue = ListBuffer[Int]()
defaultValue: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]

scala> val hash = new HashMap[String, ListBuffer[Int]]
hash: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]] = Map()

scala> hash.getOrElseUpdate("A", defaultValue).append(1)

scala> hash.getOrElseUpdate("B", defaultValue).append(2)

scala> println(hash("B").head)
2
```